# SocketMobile Scanner : How to detect barcode or QR get scanned?

Tags: socketscan, socketmobile

I am using SocketMobile scanner 7Xi in SPP(Application Mode) for iOS app. I have integrated the [scanapisdk](https://github.com/SocketMobile/singleentry-ios) SDK.

On scanning Barcode or QR code below delegate is called :

`- (void) onDecodedDataResult:(long)result device:(DeviceInfo *)device decodedData:(ISktScanDecodedData*)decodedData
{
      NSString * scannedText = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(const char *)[decodedData getData]];
}`

**Here, how would I get to know if scan happened on Barcode or QR ?**

I want to detect whether Barcode or QR was scanned.

Is it possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ISktScanDecodedData has two methods which you could use to determine the barcode type

- `getSymbologyID` - returns an int
- `getSymbologyName` - returns a string

I'd recommend using the first one, because the name is subject to change.

```
- (void) onDecodedDataResult:(long)result device:(DeviceInfo *)device decodedData:(ISktScanDecodedData*)decodedData
{
    NSString * scannedText = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(const char *)[decodedData getData]];
    int symbologyId = [decodedData getSymbologyID];

    if (symbologyId == ISktScanSymbology.id.kSktScanSymbologyQRCode) {
        // do something
    } else if (symbologyId == /* INSERT "BARCODE" SYMBOLOGY ID HERE */ ) {
        // do something else
    }
}
```

If by "barcode" you mean any linear barcode (a.k.a one-dimensional barcode), you will need to specify all the different [types of linear barcodes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barcode#Linear_barcodes) in your code